# Retry a promise step

Tags: javascript, promise, es6-promise

Suppose I have the the following Promise chain:

```
var result = Promise.resolve(filename)
    .then(unpackDataFromFile)
    .then(transformData)
    .then(compileDara)
    .then(writeData);
```

Now I have not only one `transformData` function but two or more, stored in an array. I want to try the first one, and if the `compileData` function fails, try the second one and so on until either `compileData` succeeds or the array of `transformData` functions is exhausted.

Can someone give me an example on how to implement this?

Running all `transformData` functions and give the result array to `compileData` is not an option, since the functions are very expensive and I want to run as few as possible of them.

`transformData` itself also returns a Promise, if that helps.

Answer (score 2):

I would start by isolating the notion of trying a number of promises until one succeeds:

```
function tryMultiple([promise, ...rest]) {
  if (!promise) throw new Error("no more to try");
  return promise.catch(() => tryMultiple(rest));
}
```

Now write a handler which tries each combination of transforming and compiling:

```
function transformAndCompile(transformers) {
  return function(data) {
    return tryMultiple(transformers.map(t => t(data).then(compileData)));
  };
}
```

Now the top level is just:

```
var result = Promise.resolve(filename)
  .then(unpackDataFromFile)
  .then(transformAndCompile(transformers))
  .then(writeData);
```

By the way, `Promise.resolve(filename).then(unpackDataFromFile)` is just a roundabout way of saying `unpackDataFromFile(filename)`.

Comment: Aren't you executing every transformer, even if the first one succeeds?

Comment: @jfriend00 I will run some tests, but the "recursive" call is in the `catch` clause, so how would it run if the transformer (and compiler) succeeded?

Comment: You're running `transformers.map()`.  That's synchronous so it will process the entire transformers array and call `t(data).then(compileData)` on all of them synchronously before you even get to `tryMultiple()`.  Then, you will one by one examine the resulting promises until you find one that worked, but ALL the operations have been fired off and you're just looking in order to see which one succeeded.  That's way different than running one operation, see if it succeeds.  If so, you're done.  If not, run the next one.

Comment: The recursive call is just examining results - that's not where the operations were started.  They were all started long before that in the `.map()`.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
// various transformer functions to try in order to be tried
var transformers = [f1, f2, f3, f4];    

function transformFile(filename) {
    // initialize tIndex to select next transformer function
    var tIndex = 0;
    var p = unpackDataFromFile(filename);

    function run() {
          return p.then(transformers[tIndex++])
          .then(compileData)
          .catch(function(err) {
              if (tIndex < transformers.length) {
                // execute the next transformer, returning
                // a promise so it is linked into the chain
                return run();
              } else {
                // out of transformers, so reject and stop
                throw new Error("No transformer succeeded");
              }
          }).then(writeData);

    }
    return run();
}

transformFile("someData.txt").then(function(finalResult) {
    // succeeded here
}).catch(function(err) {
    // error here
});
```

Here's how this works:

1. Sets up a `tIndex` variable that indexes into the array of transformer functions.
2. Calls `unpackDataFromFile(filename)` and saves the resulting promise.
3. Then executes the sequence `p.then(transformer).then(compileData)` using the first transformer.  If that succeeds, it calls writeData and returns the resulting promise.
4. If either the transformer or compileData fails, then it goes to the next transformer function and starts over.  The key here to making this work is that in the `.catch()` handler, it returns a new promise which chains into the originally returned promise.  Each new call to `run()` is chained onto the original promise from `unpackDataFromFile()` which allows you to reuse that result.

---

Here's a bit more generic implementation that makes an iterator for an array that iterates until the iterator callback returns a promise that fulfills.

```
// Iterate an array using an iterator that returns a promise
// Stop iterating as soon as you get a fulfilled promise from the iterator
// Pass:
//    p - Initial promise (can be just Promise.resolve(data))
//    array - array of items to pass to the iterator one at a time
//    fn - iterator function that returns a promise
//         iterator called as fn(data, item)
//             data - fulfilled value of promise passed in
//             item - array item for this iteration
function iterateAsyncUntilSuccess(p, array, fn) {
    var index = 0;

    function next() {
        if (index < array.length) {
            var item = array[index++];
            return p.then(function(data) {
                return fn(data, item).catch(function(err) {
                    // if this one fails, try the next one
                    return next();
                });
            });
        } else {
            return Promise.reject(new Error("End of data with no operation successful"));
        }
    }

    return next();
}

// Usage:
// various transformer functions to try in order to be tried
var transformers = [f1, f2, f3, f4];    

iterateAsyncUntil(unpackDataFromFile(filename), transformers, function(data, item) {
    return item(data).then(compileData);
}).then(writeData).then(function(result) {
    // successfully completed here
}).catch(function(err) {
    // error here
});
```

Comment: Sure, this implementation is more efficient than torazaburo's. But instead of two functions we now have one very specific function and thus zero reusability.

Comment: @LUH3417 - Yeah, but you listed a requirement to **since the functions are very expensive and I want to run as few as possible of them.** and torozaburo's implementation runs all the functions all the time, even if the very first one succeeds.  This one runs a function at a time and stops when the first one succeeds.  One could probably make this concept more generic if that is also a requirement.  Sorry, but I'm just writing the quickest code that meets the requirements you listed.  I'm surprised if you think torazaburo's code meets your requirement to run as few functions as possible.

Comment: I'm not the OP and sorry for not reading the question thoroughly. You are right. Personally, I don't like such micro optimization though.

Comment: @LUH3417 - Sorry, I confused you with the OP.  It's not exactly micro-optimization to avoid reading and processing a bunch of unnecessary files in a server.  That can be real meaningful work to a server trying to process requests from lots of users and is often an important requirement.  Avoiding reading and processing whole files is not exactly micro-optimization.

Comment: @LUH3417 - If I gave you 20 filenames in order and asked you to efficiently return the first file that meets a specific criteria (which requires reading and processing the file) would you write a single function, run it on all 20 files and then examine the results in order to find the first one that meets the criteria or would you run it on the first one, check the results, if it didn't meet the criteria then run it on the next one and so on?

Comment: No, no, I think this is just a misunderstanding. Your solution is evidently better. I would just try to split `transformFile` into smaller functions, since it is currently very specific, tailored to exactly the given task.

Comment: @LUH3417 - I took you up on your challenge and I created a more generic iterator solution.

Comment: This wasn't a challenge at all :D. Looks better now. Can't up vote though, because I already did.

Answer (score -1):

The following should do what you want most idiomatically:

```
var transformers = [transformData, transformData2];

var result = unpackDataFromFile(filename)
  .then(function transpile(data, i = 0) {
    return transformers[i](data).then(compileData)
      .catch(e => ++i < transformers.length? transpile(data, i) : Promise.reject(e));
  })
  .then(writeData);
```

Basically you recurse on the transformers array, using `.catch()`.

Comment: The OP has several transformers but only one compileData. He had to build that nested array in the first place. Why not simply `function transpile(data, i = 0) { return [transformers[i], compileData].reduce((p, f) => p.then(f), Promise.resolve(data)).catch(e => i < transpilers.length && transpile(data, i + 1)); }`. This adaption also avoids mutation of global state.

Comment: @LUH3417 Sold. Updated answer (we don't really need `reduce` anymore either).