# How to poll an API as part of a $.Deferred()

Tags: javascript, jquery, promise, jquery-deferred

The below non-functional example should explain what I'm trying to do, I just don't understand the pattern I need to use to accomplish it. I tried googling to understand polling and deferred, but I couldn't find anything I could understand.

I have a function which polls an API, and I want to wait for that polling to return an expected result (waiting for the endpoint to indicate something has changed) before continuing with my main function. What am I doing wrong?

Edit: I should add that what SEEMS to go wrong with the code below is that even though `deferred.resolve()` eventually gets called, it seems it isn't the same `deferred` that got returned, so the `when` never gets activated in `main()`. I'm guessing it has to do with the timeout, meaning `deferred` get clobbered on the first repeat. That is my assumption, anyways.

```
function pollAPI() {
     var deferred = $.Deferred();

     $.ajax({                                                                  
       url: url,                                       
       contentType: 'application/JSON',                                      
       method: 'GET'                                                         
     }).done(function(data){                                                                                                                              
         if (!desiredResult) {                                                 
             setTimeout(function() {                                         
               pollAPI();                            
             }, 1000);                                                       
         } else {                                                            
           deferred.resolve();
         }                                                                                                                                           
     }).error(deferred.reject());                                            

     return deferred.promise();
 }

function main() {
    $.when(pollAPI()).then(function() {
        // do something now that the API has returned the expected result
    });
```

Comment: each call to pollAPI creates a new deferred, nothing gets clobbered - try `deferred.resolve(pollAPI())` in the setTimeout

Comment: Wouldn't that cause the first deferred to resolve, thus causing the `when` to trigger even though it is not ready?

Comment: yes, it will resolve to an as yet unresolved promise - so, should not be an issue - see section 2.3 in [Promise/A+ specification](https://promisesaplus.com/) - jquery possibly follows this spec, but there are significant departures from the Promise/A+ spec in some earlier versions of jQuery

Comment: Well I gave it a shot, and while you're right that it didn't cause an issue, it also did not trigger the `when` in `main()` when the desiredResult finally came back as expected, so I seem to still be in the same boat.

Comment: I've never trusted jQuery's so called "Deferred" anyway - so it doesn't surprise me

Comment: see if [this](https://jsfiddle.net/t2oe0f97/1/) is of any use (that code wont do anything, obviously, just putting it there so you can copy)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use chaining of subsequent calls to the `pollAPI()` function to create a single promise that has others chained onto it.  That would work like this:

```
// utility function to create a promise that is resolved after a delay
$.promiseDelay = function(t) {
    return $.Deferred(function(def) {
        setTimeout(def.resolve, t);
    }).promise();
}

function pollAPI() {
    return $.ajax({
        url: url,
        contentType: 'application/JSON',
        method: 'GET'
    }).then(function(data) {
        // some logic here to test if we have desired result
        if (!desiredResult) {
            // chain the next promise onto it after a delay
            return $.promiseDelay(1000).then(pollAPI);
        } else {
            // return resolved value
            return someValue;
        }
    });
}

function main() {
    pollAPI().then(function(result) {
        // got desired result here
    }, function(err) {
        // ended with an error here
    });
}
```

This has the following benefits:

1. No unnecessary promise is created to try to surround the ajax call that already has a promise.  This avoids one of the [common promise anti-patterns](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/wiki/Promise-anti-patterns).
2. Subsequent calls to the API just chain to the original promise.
3. There is no need to use `$.when()` when you just have a single promise.  You can just use `.then()` directly on it.
4. All errors automatically percolate back to the original promise.
5. This uses the ES6-standard `.then()` (which actually becomes more legitimately standard in jQuery 3.x - though it works in jQuery 1.x and 2.x with its own non-standard quirks) which makes this logic more compatible with other promise-producing async functions.

Also, a number of other retry ideas here: [Promise Retry Design Patterns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38213668/promise-retry-design-patterns/38214203#38214203)

Comment: This is more or less working, and I appreciate the references. I am working through them to better understand the pattern. The only part I'm still confused about is the `return someValue`. If I set someValue to 'foobar' before the return, and then `console.log(result)`, then `undefined` is printed to the console. Am I misundertanding something about returning values through the the chain back to main()?

Comment: @fildred13 - You'd have to show me (perhaps as an addition onto your question) exactly what you're trying because `return someValue` (where you actually put a real value in place of `someValue`) will propagate back a resolved value to the original promise and will show up in `main()` as the `result` argument if you use code like I've shown.

Comment: Oh I see what's wrong - for me, the `then` of pollAPI() isn't being called, even when i `return someValue`. Basically, the pollAPI() function finishes, but the `then` never gets called. Thoughts?

Comment: @fildred13 - Again, you'll have to show me what code you're actually using for me to know where you went wrong in the implementation.  In my answer, you will get either a resolved value or an error back unless you loop infinitely and your logic never accepts a desired result and returns a value.

Comment: I've worked on this for awhile, and improved my surrounding calls according to the patterns you suggested, but it seems that when I call promiseDelay, the pollAPI function returns, causing `main()` to continue with the `then`. So I guess I'm chaining the promises incorrectly, but I can't see where. I don't want to clutter the question with specific code, so here is a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/8sjcLjrt/ Once I know what was causing the problem, I'll comment here. Help would be appreciated though - I'm stumped!

Comment: The current state of that fiddle, is that the console prints, in order: 
`not finished yet, retrying`
`2. job status found, so storing states and resolving`
`1. getJobStatus finished, so returning and finishing promise`
So even though I return the `promiseDelay` in `getJobStatus()`, for some reason the `then` in createLinkAPIJob acts as if the promise got resolved.

Comment: Since I had to use an anonymous function as the callback for the promiseDelay().then(), I had to return the call to pollAPI in order to keep the chain of promises going. Thanks so much for this answer, it helped me understand promises much better.