# Retry promise until resolved (Too much recursion error)

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, es6-promise

I was trying to test if I could have a promise retry until it resolved, but it keeps giving "too much recursion" error and I can't understand why it doesn't stop after the 3rd recursion.

The following code is trying to emulate a failed query request to a server, which comes from a non-promise function.

```
function nonPromiseCallback(x, resolve, reject){    
  if(x < 3){
    reject(x)
  }else{
    resolve(x)
  }
}

function tryUntilThree(x){
  return new Promise( (resolve, reject) => {
    nonPromiseCallback(x, resolve, tryUntilThree(x+1));
  })
}

tryUntilThree(1)
.then(console.log);
```

Comment: check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38213668/promise-retry-design-patterns) answer, might help you

Comment: You get too much recursion because *tryUntilThree* is called too many times. Notice that you have written *tryUntilThree(x+1)*, ie the engine has to resolve the call to *tryUntilThree* before it can call *nonPromiseCallback*. You have an infinite loop there.

Comment: @some: Mind if i quote your comment in my answer? :)

Comment: @vicbyte I don't mind. I added special quotes around the code (in my comment they where in italics)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are interested in a promise failure, you could use the catch handler.

As to why your code doesn't work, heres a good explaination by [some](https://stackoverflow.com/users/36866/some) (also in the comment):

> You get too much recursion because `tryUntilThree` is called too many
>   times. Notice that you have written `tryUntilThree(x+1)`, ie the engine
>   has to resolve the call to `tryUntilThree` before it can call
>   `nonPromiseCallback`. You have an infinite loop there.

```js
function nonPromiseCallback(x, resolve, reject){    
  if(x < 3){
    reject(x)
  }else{
    resolve(x)
  }
}

function tryUntilThree(x){
  return new Promise( (resolve, reject) => 
    nonPromiseCallback(x, resolve, reject)
  ).catch(() => 
    tryUntilThree(x + 1)
  )
}

tryUntilThree(1)
.then(console.log);
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with the `nonPromiseCallback` method call, instead of a function reference, you are passing an actual function and then calling that function.

Problem:

```
nonPromiseCallback(x, resolve, tryUntilThree(x+1));
```

Fix:

```
nonPromiseCallback(x, resolve, tryUntilThree);
```

and

```
reject(x+1);
```

Comment: @Bergi I pointed the fix for the call stack issue he is facing (infinite recursion), I haven't pointed out any thing else since I don't know what he wants from the code.

Answer (score 1):

I tried your code but got the `TypeError: reject is not a function`.
That is because you pass in `tryUntilThree(x+1)` which executes the function before passing it to `nonPromiseCallback`.

So i came up with this code, to try to accomplish what you want.

```
let res;    // used for keeping a reference to the original resolve
function nonPromiseCallback(x, resolve, reject){
    if(x < 3){
      reject(x + 1);
    }
    else{
      resolve(x);
    }
}

function tryUntilThree(x){
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
        if(!res){
            res = resolve;
        }
        nonPromiseCallback(x, res, tryUntilThree);
    });
}

tryUntilThree(1)
.then(res => console.log("RESULT:", res));
```

`let res;`, this variable is used for keeping a reference to the original resolve, so that the `.then` executes.

Answer (score 1):

As I said in my comment, to your question, you had an infinite loop since to call `nonPromiseCallback` the result of `tryUntilThree` was needed... and to get that, `tryUntilThree` was called... and it was looping until memory was exhausted or the end of the universe, whichever came first.

You need to make two changes:

```
function nonPromiseCallback(x, resolve, reject){
  if(x < 3){
    reject(x+1) // the increment of x is moved to here.
  }else{
    resolve(x)
  }
}

function tryUntilThree(x){
  return new Promise( (resolve, reject) => {
    nonPromiseCallback(x, resolve, tryUntilThree); // Just pass the function, it will be called later
  })
}

tryUntilThree(1)
.then(console.log);
```

If you can use [async](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) and [await](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await) (new features since 2017) you could solve it like this (I moved the decision of maximum number of tries to the calling function) :

```
function nonPromiseCallback(x, resolve, reject){
  if(x < 3){
    reject(x+1)
  }else{
    resolve(x)
  }
}

async function tryUntilThree(){
  const maxAttempts = 3;
  let attempt = 1;

  do {
    try {
      // "await" waits for the prommise to resolve or reject.
      // If it is rejected, an error will be thrown. That's why
      // this part of the code is inside a try/catch-block.
      const result = await new Promise( (resolve, reject) =>
        nonPromiseCallback( attempt, resolve, reject )
      );
      return result; // Return the result from nonPromiseCallback
    }
    catch (error) {
      // The nonPromiseCallback failed. Try again
      attempt += 1;
    }
  } while ( attempt <= maxAttempts );

  // Signal error after all retires.
  throw Error(`Failure, even after ${maxAttempts} tries`);
}

tryUntilThree()
.then(console.log);
```