# Retry on Javascript.Promise.reject a limited number of times or until success

Tags: javascript, es6-promise

I have a function say `myMainFunction` that is called from a client, that in turn calls `mypromisified` function.

**Scenario:**
`mypromisified` function can fail intermittently and I need to call this function with a delay (at an exponential increase) until success or until max no of tries reached.

**What I have so far**

The following code illustrates my scenario and repeats itself until success, *but it tries indefinitely and not until certain count is reached*

```js
// called once from the client
myMainFuntion();

function rejectDelay(delay, reason) {
   // call main function at a delayed interval until success 
   // but would want to call this only a limited no of times
    setTimeout(() => {
      myMainFuntion(); // calling main function again here but with a delay
    }, delay);
}


function myMainFuntion() {
  var delay = 100;
  var tries = 3;
  tryAsync().catch(rejectDelay.bind(null, delay));
}

function tryAsync() {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    var rand = Math.random();
    console.log(rand);
    if (rand < 0.8) {
      reject(rand);
    } else {
      resolve();
    }
  });

}
```

`while` loop inside the `rejectDelay` would certainly not work as the counter would increment even before the actual function inside setInterval is executed, so am unsure as to how to go about this? so...

I tried `promisifying` the `setInterval` something like this knowing it will fail :( as it doesnt decrement the counter, but not sure how to get it right either .

```js
function rejectDelay(delay, maximumTries, reason) {
  return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    console.log(tries + ' remaining');
    if (--maximumTries > 0) {
      setTimeout(function() {
        foo();
      }, 500);
    } 
  });
}
function myMainFunction() {
  var delay = 100;
  var maximumTries = 3;
  tryAsync().catch(rejectDelay.bind(null, delay, maximumTries));
}
```

Comment: Related answers: [Promise retry design patterns](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38213668/promise-retry-design-patterns/38214203#38214203) and [Retry a promise step](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37993365/retry-a-promise-step/37995874#37995874)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Using a couple of helper functions I've used a lot, this becomes very easy

The "helpers"

```
Promise.wait = (time) => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, time || 0));
Promise.retry = (cont, fn, delay) => fn().catch(err => cont > 0 ? Promise.wait(delay).then(() => Promise.retry(cont - 1, fn, delay)) : Promise.reject('failed'));
```

The code:

```
function myMainFuntion() {
      var delay = 100;
      var tries = 3;
      Promise.retry(tries, tryAsync, delay);
}
```

> ES5 versions of the helpers

```
Promise.wait = function (time) {
    return new Promise(function (resolve) {
        return setTimeout(resolve, time || 0);
    });
};
Promise.retry = function (cont, fn, delay) {
    return fn().catch(function (err) {
        return cont > 0 ? Promise.wait(delay).then(function () {
            return Promise.retry(cont - 1, fn, delay);
        }) : Promise.reject('failed');
    });
};
```

Comment: thanks a ton for a terse solution :) . I understand the recursive call made on `retry`, but unable to get my head around the wait function -> I see that you are returning a new Promise, but not explicilty resolving or rejecting the same? - which in my head means `.then` on `Promise.wait()` would never be called? Do you mind explaning it to me a bit more? thank you in advance 
PS: I know it is working from the rip off :) that i made here to https://jsfiddle.net/jayas_godblessall/j50u8br9/ - but as  mentioned - not working in my head :(

Comment: the first argument to `setTimeout` is a function to run ... it's set to `resolve` ... therefore resolve gets called after `time` ms

Comment: Nice recursive definition of Promise.retry! Note that the function "fn" will actually be called "cont"+1 times here, unless you compare cont to 1.

Comment: Depends on how you think of retry I guess

Comment: Would `Promise.reject(err)` work to propagate the error if the error message is needed after all retries fail?

Comment: @NobleUplift - I think so, but this is such ugly monkeypatch code!!! Whoever wrote it should be ashamed ... and I am :p

Answer (score 0):

A slightly different approach that uses "asynchronous recursion" to call a nested function within a function that returns a promise:

```js
function retry( func, maxTries, delay) {
    var reTry = 0;
    return new Promise( function(resolve, reject) {
        function callFunc() {
          try
          {
              func().then(resolve, function( reason) {
                  if( ++reTry >= maxTries) {
                      reject( reason);
                  }
                  else {
                      setTimeout( callFunc,
                         typeof delay=="function" ? delay( retry) : delay );
                  }
              });
          }
          catch(e) {
              reject(e);
          }
        }
        callFunc();      
    });
}

//  ******* run snippet to test ********


var retryCount = 0;
function getDelay( n) {
//    return 100 * n*n + 500; // for example
      ++ retryCount;
      return 100;  // for testing

}

function testFunc() {
    return Math.random() < 0.8 ? Promise.reject("too many tries") : Promise.resolve( "success");
}

retry( testFunc, 5, getDelay).then(
 function(data) { console.log("data: %s, retryCount %s", data, retryCount);},
 function(reason){console.log("reason: %s, retryCount %s", reason, retryCount);}
)
```